# Lua script refusing to work on Logitech G HUB application

Tags: lua, scripting

I am a new user to stackoverflow and i apologize if i make newbies mistakes, anyway, here's the code

```
--=================================== Hiro's Logitech Script =========================================---
--=========================================================================================---
--=====================Mouse Bind Keys - Keyboard bind Keys (only logitech)==========================---

---[[ Keyboard Binds ]]--

local Havoc=  nil
local R301 = 3
local Devotion= nil
local Flatline= nil

---[[ Mouse Key Binds ]]--

local Havoc=  nil
local R301 = 3
local Devotion= nil
local Flatline= nil

--============================================---

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
local recoil = falseB
local weapon = 0
function OnEvent(event, arg)

  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == R301) or
(event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == R301_Keyboard) then
    recoil = not recoil
    weapon = arg
    if (recoil == false) then
      OutputLogMessage("OFF-Macro-R301\n")
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        PressAndReleaseKey("capslock")
      end
    else
      OutputLogMessage("ON-NoRecoil-R301\n")
      if not IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        PressAndReleaseKey("capslock")
end
end


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 elseif weapon == R301 or weapon ==R301_Keyboard then
       if recoil then

 if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
        repeat
        if   IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                  Sleep(100)
                  if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                      MoveMouseRelative(-20, 25)
                      Sleep(10)
                      MoveMouseRelative(20, -20)
                      Sleep(10)
                     until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)  
                    end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
end
end
end
```

However nothing happens after i activate the script using mouse 3 button

When I activate the script with my mouse 3 (scrollwheel) click, the caps lock key turns on/off and the script also has this message 'ON-NoRecoil-R301' or the off alternative, which indicates that atleast the first half of the code is functioning, but the second half where the magic happens does not. To my understanding the code should simulate a shaking mouse input, but that's just not happening. I thought it could be other issues such as hardware/software corruption whatsoever, so i reinstalled windows, the application, basically tried every method i could find on the internet, but it still just won't work, please help

Comment: The script should be active only after press-and-hold RMB, then press LMB.  If it does not work, try inserting `Sleep(10)` just after `if recoil then`.